# Removing supend and hibernate privileges

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, suspend, hibernate, polkit

On OpenSUSE 12.1 x86_64, Gnome 3.2 . I want to remove the suspend and hibernate options from the Gnome (Shell) menu as

- suspend makes no sense IMO for a desktop
- hibernate has a slight tendency to lock up

I've found that I should configure these privileges using polkit. I've dropped a file named `90-disable-suspend.conf` ( also tried `90-disable-suspend.pkla` ) in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d` with the following contents:

```
[Disable Suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate;org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

However, running `pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.upower.suspend --process $$` prints nothing and has an exit code of 0 , and the menu entries are still present. AFAICT these are provided by `gnome-shell-extension-alt-status-menu` package.

How can I remove the suspend and hibernate entries from the Gnome Shell menu and leave only Power Off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d` is reserved for configuration files.

You should put your file in a subdirectory of `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority`  and with extension `.pkla`. The directory `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` should be ok too, but can be modified by updagraded/installed packages, so better to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really easy answer to this.

Go to `/usr/sbin`.
Delete symbolic links `pm-hibernate`, `pm-suspend` and `pm-suspend-hybrid`.

Now when either 'Suspend' or 'Hibernate' is selected from the menu it will just do a 'Lock Screen' instead.

If you want to me doubly sure, go to `/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin` and move `pm-action` to `pm-action.mv` as this is the executable that the above symbolic links pointed to.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I'd rather not touch files under /usr since they will get restored on an update.